# Using openRTSP to record from Eufy Cam 2 Pro

Tags: ffmpeg, video, nas, webcam, rtsp

I have a couple of Eufy Cam 2 Pros. I want to record the RTSP streams to my NAS.

I have tried the built-in NAS service, which only works with synology, as well as many open source video recording software, but all have different problems.

I therefore want to use something simple & open source and record the camera streams to my generic internal storage.

The main issue seems to be the Eufy cam only streams video when it's internally triggered to save battery life.

Mostly through trial and error and countless hours I have managed to find a set of commands that can record the streams when they happen:

```
openRTSP -t -b 10000000 -B 10000000 -v -H rtsp://user:password@cam_IP/path | ffmpeg -i - -c:v copy cam_name-$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M-%S").mp4
```

The issue is this errors and stops 'listening' if the stream isn't active.  I was going to try to create a script that runs every few seconds and first looks to see if the openRTSP is already running before running openRTSP.

This seems like a very noob / inelegant solution, but I cannot find an openRTSP switch (or other solution) that just constantly listens for streams and records them to separate files when they are sent.

All help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: This is likely a hardware limitation like RTSP not being available at all for the regular flood light https://support.eufylife.com/s/article/Does-Floodlight-Cam-support-RTSP-NAS 

and indoor cams reducing continuous RTSP stream to only 1080p. Probably because the CPU can't handle it, thus will never be turned on by software updates. Too bad as there is no real alternative floodlight that can do 24/7 RTSP and local storage or PoE data.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use only openRTSP, with the suitable options?

```
$ openRTSP -D 1 -c -B 10000000-b 10000000 -q -Q -F ip_cam -d 28800 -P 900 -t  rtsp://192.168.xx.xx/11
```

Some options explained:

```
     -D 1 # Quit if no packets for 1 second or more 
     -c # Continuously record,after completion of -d timeframe
     -B 10000000 # Input buffer of 10 MB 
     -b 10000000 # Output buffer 10MB (to file) 
     -q # Produce files in QuickTime format 
     -Q # Display QOS statistics
     -F ip_cam # Prefix output filenames with this text 
     -d 28800 # Run openRTSP 28800 seconds
     -P 900 # Start a new output file every 900 seconds
     -t # Request camera end stream over TCP, not UDP (slower but packets are checked)
      rtsp://192.168.xx.xx/11 # Camera's RTSP URL
```

That works for me, using an iegeek g20 ip camera and an old rpi 2, it listens for streams and records them into separate files. A kind of ghetto cheap rpi nvr.
There several different configuration and options I don't use, just explore them.
http://www.live555.com/openRTSP/

Or alternatively you could use ffmpeg

```
ffmpeg -i "rtsp://192.168.xx.xx/11" -c copy -reset_timestamps 1  ip_cam_file.avi
```

Remember you can change the resolution here changing from 11 to 12 in the rstp address.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely a [hardware limitation like RTSP not being available at all for the regular flood light](https://support.eufylife.com/s/article/Does-Floodlight-Cam-support-RTSP-NAS) and indoor cams reducing continuous RTSP stream to only 1080p. Probably because the CPU can't handle it, thus will never be turned on by software updates. Too bad as there is no real alternative floodlight that can do 24/7 RTSP and local storage or PoE data.